# UART receive string

Tags: c, arrays, string, msp430

I am using an MSP430 and writing code in C.  I am receiving characters (working) via UART and placing them into an array rxDataArray.  Since I am using an MSP430G2211, I have limited memory.  The maximum array size is 50 and any more it won't build/load and says out of space.

My MSP430 is communicating to a ESP8266 module (wifi) where I am using "AT" commands.  I am receive an echo of my AT command, followed by a response (ex. AT+RST responds with AT+RST...ok).  I am confused using C, how I can make a string with just the "ok" response and check if it worked correctly.  I have the data in the array, just not sure how to pick certain elements of the array, make a string, and compare that to "ok" response. I am used to using CString in C++ and am confused how to do this in C.

```
/--------------------------------------------------------------------
// Timer_A UART - Receive Interrupt Handler
//-------------------------------------------------------------------
#if defined(__TI_COMPILER_VERSION__) || defined(__IAR_SYSTEMS_ICC__)
#pragma vector = TIMERA1_VECTOR
__interrupt void Timer_A1_ISR(void)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
void __attribute__ ((interrupt(TIMERA1_VECTOR))) Timer_A1_ISR (void)
#else
#error Compiler not supported!
#endif
{  
static unsigned char rxBitCnt = 8;
static unsigned char rxData = 0;

switch (__even_in_range(TAIV, TAIV_TAIFG)) { // Use calculated branching
    case TAIV_TACCR1:                        // TACCR1 CCIFG - UART RX
        TACCR1 += UART_TBIT;                 // Add Offset to CCRx
        if (TACCTL1 & CAP) {                 // Capture mode = start bit edge
            TACCTL1 &= ~CAP;                 // Switch capture to compare mode
            TACCR1 += UART_TBIT_DIV_2;       // Point CCRx to middle of D0
        }
        else {
            rxData >>= 1;
            if (TACCTL1 & SCCI) {            // Get bit waiting in receive latch
                rxData |= 0x80;
            }
            rxBitCnt--;
            if (rxBitCnt == 0) {             // All bits RXed?
                rxBuffer = rxData;           // Store in global variable

                if (rxDataCnt < 50)
                {
                    rxDataArray[rxDataCnt] = rxBuffer;
                    rxDataCnt++;
                }
                else
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    for (i; i<50-1; i++)
                    {
                        rxDataArray[i] = rxDataArray[i+1];
                    }

                    rxDataArray[50-1] = rxBuffer;
                }

                rxBitCnt = 8;                // Re-load bit counter
                TACCTL1 |= CAP;              // Switch compare to capture mode
                __bic_SR_register_on_exit(LPM0_bits);  // Clear LPM0 bits from 0(SR)
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Since the 'string' may be spread over several interrupts, I would probably use a char-by-char state-machine to look for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn OFF echo by sending `ATE0` command.

Also to find the intended string response please follow below steps:

1. Enable UART Transmit and Receive Interrupt.
2. After completing your command transmission you will start receiving data in UART ISR.
3. In the receive interrupt start a timer of say 1 second(You need to consider baud-rate for exact calculation).
4. Make track of number of received bytes in UART ISR.
5. Now after timer expires add `null` to end of last received byte in buffer.

Now,You can use string manipulation functions of C to find the intended response.

Comment: With the ATE0 command, it makes life much easier.  I also removed \r and \n hex (0x0A) and (0x0D) for getting in the buffer array, so now I can verify the response and reset my buffer each time.  Thanks for the help!